Domain of injectivity of a rational map $\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}$ where $P(z)$ and $Q(z)$ are polynomials.
Question: Let $P(z)$ and $Q(z)$ be two polynomials with degree $m$ and $n$ respectively with $m>n$. Given that both are injective in the set $A=\{z\in\mathbb{C}: \beta \leq Arg(z) \leq \frac{\pi}{2}~\mbox{and}~ |z| \geq M\}$ for some $M>0$ (where $\beta \in (\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2m} , \frac{\pi}{2})$ and $Arg(z)$ denotes the principal argument of $z$). What can we say about the injectivity of the rational function $\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}$ in $A$? In particular, does $A$ have a proper subset where $\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}$ is injective?
My observation: I have seen that there are points in $A$ such that $\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}$ is not injective at those points, even the collection of such points may be infinite. But I am not sure whether the collection of points from $A$ where $\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}$ is not injective is bounded or not.
Can anyone point out any idea? Thank you.
